# Validate form and prevent submission

Tags: jquery, html

Using html5 form validation with `required` attributes.

When submit button is clicked, I only want to validate, not submit the form.

```
<input type="submit" id="calculate">

<script>
    $("#calculate").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents validation

        // do something else with form data
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Use submit event. `$("form").submit(function(e) {})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger the form html5 validation you can use

```
$('#myForm')[0].checkValidity();


<script>
    $("#calculate").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents form submission

        $("#form")[0].checkValidity();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I ended up with this: `if (!$("#form")[0].checkValidity()) { alert("Please enter valid values."); return; }`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using `button`instead of `input`, as:

```
<button type="button" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
```

And use JavaScript to validate the form for submission, as:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
    //Validate form
    if(formValidated()) {
        $('#formId').submit ();
    }
});
```

If you don't wanna submit just remove, `$('#formId').submit ();`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an idea/demonstration, here's a way to validate without using the required attribute -- it gives you a little more control over the validation process, and as you can see it's quite simple.

Begin by creating an array containing the IDs of all input fields to check. *(You can have groups of like fields that must be evaluated in the same way... one array/for-loop for input fields, another for checkboxes, another for text fields, etc.)*

When you `return false;` form submission is aborted.

```js
var arr = ['em','fn','ln'];
$('#myForm').submit(function(){
  for (var n=0; n<arr.length; n++){
     $('#'+arr[n]).removeClass('errorField');
     if ( arr[n] == 'em'){
        if  ( $('#'+arr[n]).val() == 'Bob' ){
           //eval email field differently
           alert('Hi Bob - you cannot complete this form');
           return false; //error condition, so abort submit
        }
     }else if ( $('#'+arr[n]).val() == ''){
        $('#'+arr[n]).addClass('errorField').focus();
        return false; //error condition, so abort submit
     }
  }

  alert("Form will now submit"); return false; //FOR DEMO ONLY
  //Submit continues
});
```

```css
.errorField{background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" action="process.php" method="post" >
  First Name: <input type="text" id="fn" name="fn" /><br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" id="ln" name="ln" /><br>
  Non-Required: <input type="text" id="nr" name="nr" /><br>
  Email: <input type="text" id="em" name="em"  /><br>
  <input type="submit" id="mybutt" value="Submit" /><br>
</form>
```